# Django data losing order when running on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a list which contains lists like `[[1, 2, 4], [5, 6,7], [8, 9,10]]` I pass the list to the template html which then loops through it and displays it as a table like below:

```
<tbody>
 {% for zone in zones %}
 <tr>
  <td>{{zone.2}}</td>
  <td>{{zone.0}} -- {{zone.1}}</td>
   </tr>
  {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
```

This is how I'm passing it:

```
return render(request, 'alpha/index.html', {"zones":zones})
```

When I'm running it locally it works as I expect it. That is, the first element in the list is presented first in the table as well. This order is lost when I push to Heroku (the zones appear randomly in the table) and I'm not sure what is causing this.

I have tried to take the elements of the list, load them into variables and pass them one by one to see if the list is losing the order somehow. This didn't help, so I'm thinking it's a problem either with Heroku's setup or I'm using Django wrong.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to show where `zones` is coming from in the view in the first place.

Comment: If you convert this `list` into a `dict`, say: `{'first': [1, 2, 4], 'second': [5, 6, 7], 'third': [8, 9, 10]}`, would that work ? I don't think this has to do with Heroku.

Comment: @nik_m I have tried that as well. Still losing the order.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by passing the sorted list like so:

```
return render(request, "index.html", {"zones":sorted(zones.values())})
```

I'm still not sure why it's messing up the order (maybe Heroku or Django) but this did it for me.